# How to return QtListWidget from function

Tags: qt, object, return

I am looking to create a QListWidget in a function and then return it. I get this error: main.cpp:112: error: could not convert 'lw' from 'QListWidget*' to 'QListWidget' return lw;^  Anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong?

my function:

header:

```
private slots:
    QListWidget create();
```

cpp

```
QListWidget Main::create(){

    QListWidget* lw = new QListWidget;

    lw->addItem(new QListWidgetItem("one"));
    lw->addItem(new QListWidgetItem("two"));
    return lw;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns a pointer to `QListWidget`, so you must declare it in this way:

h

```
QListWidget* create();
```

cpp

```
QListWidget* Main::create(){
///etc
```

Answer (score 3):

The method signature should be:

```
QListWidget* create();
```

That is, you return a pointer. You cannot return `QListWidget` or any other non-copyable `QObject` by value.

Answer (score 0):

You'r just able to return a pointer to your QListWidget. You can also try to build your QListWidget over a parameter in you function.

```
void buildListWidget(QListWidget &aListWidget /*referenz to a QListWidget*/)
{
  //add stuff to aListWidget
}
```

Your function call like:

```
QListWidget list;
buildListWidget(list);
//use list
```